# Is there a way to get all keys from a value in a multimap?

Tags: java, guava, multimap

Say I have a guava Multimap.  I have a value, "Foo", that may belong to one or more keys.  Is there any way I can figure out which keys contain an entry "Foo"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can invert the Multimap. For this you can use the method [`Multimaps.invertFrom`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#invertFrom%28com.google.common.collect.Multimap,%20M%29).

For example, if your Multimap is a `Multimap<String, String>`

```
Multimap<String, String> invertedMultimap = Multimaps.invertFrom(myMultimap, ArrayListMultimap.<String, String>create());
```

Comment: I knew there had to be an easy way to do this!  Thanks! :)

Comment: If you've got an `ImmutableMultimap`, it has a built-in `inverse()` method.

Answer (score 7):

If you have an `ImmutableMultimap`, which is a good idea whenever possible, you can call `.inverse().get(v)` on it.